# Tool to create folder stucture

Tags: structure, cross-platform, directory

I'm not sure if im asking my question in the correct place. I am looking for a tool, preferably cross platform (win/linux mainly) that gives me the ability to create a folder structure. I basically need a tool to quickly create a set folders as follows:

Lname, Fname
-DATE
--Source
--WIP
--Final
--Proof

The only tool i found was a tool by epicsoft and it seems they are no longer in business.

Or if this doesn't exist if someone could point me to some tutorials or something that will explain how to do this and how to create a GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

a quick cross-platform language like java or python can do this for you very quickly.
in java

```
import java.io.File;

// demonstrates how to create a directory in java
public class JavaCreateDirectoryExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    File dir = new File("Lname"); //this puts the directory in the current working directory

    // attempt to create the directory here
    boolean successful = dir.mkdir(); //you can use mkdirs() to make several folders at once, like Lname/Date/ThisDir/
    if (successful)
    {
      // creating the directory succeeded
      System.out.println("directory was created successfully");
    }
    else
    {
      // creating the directory failed
      System.out.println("failed trying to create the directory");
    }
  }
}
```

You can then do this several times to create the structure. and then run that code from the shell.